# Why nginx not serve .gz files?

Tags: symfony, nginx, assets

I have next nginx conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<sname>.+?).site.ru$;
root /var/www/kvz/$sname.site.ru/web;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/static/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires     max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
    add_header  Last-Modified "";
    add_header  ETag "";
}

# DEV
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
# PROD
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/$sname-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/$sname-error.log debug;

}
```

And in my `static` directory exists file.js and file.js.gz. But when i request file.js nginx not serve file.js.gz. Why? In [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/241347/how-do-i-serve-pre-gzipped-files-with-nginx-so-that-theyll-be-shown-as-text-in) question writed that this work. What wrong in my config?

Comment: Do you have HttpGzipStatic nginx module?

Comment: 1) is [`ngx_http_gzip_static_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html) module enable? and 2) Is the client [accepting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) gzip?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/223509/how-can-i-see-which-flags-nginx-was-compiled-with

Comment: Yes. Module enabled.
`built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ... --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic ....`